# html alignment with text boxes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have these two text boxes i'm wnating to be side by side, Currently they are stacked ontop of eachother.

I'm getting so stressed out at this! its something stupidly simple but i cant find it!

Here is the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <strong>Date:</strong>

    <div class='input-group date datepicker' ng-model="package.dateA">
        <input type='text' id="date" ng-model="package.dateB"
               class="form-control"/>
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                  </span>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="form-group"> -->
    <strong>Time:</strong>

    <div class='input-group date timepicker' ng-model="package.timeA">
        <input type='text' id="time" ng-model="package.timeB" class="form-control"/>
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                  </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**
Heres what happens when i place the stylesheet edit on suggested in the answers
[image: image after edit]

Comment: Please, post your CSS or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DIVs are block level elements. If you want them next to each other you need to use CSS styling.

```
display: inline-block;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sabgbn16/

Comment: Please post your complete HTML and CSS. Something else in there is throwing things off. As you can see in the jsfiddle I posted they are inline with each other.

Comment: I would love to but its such a big rails application theres way to much to post (at least 22 stylesheets)

Comment: OK, maybe something in CSS is overriding the class I suggested. Can you test putting the styles as inline attributes on the input-group divs? style="display: inline-block;" and see if that works?

Comment: I've ended up using col-md-4 twice :) one way around it!

Comment: Yea seems like bootstrap makes inputs take up 100% width so as you already found out using the grids and classes they provide will fix this for you.

Answer (score 1):

> "Use the grid Luke!"

Since you're working with bootstrap I'd recommend using the grid layout. [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Date:</strong>

            <div class='input-group date datepicker' ng-model="package.dateA">
                <input type='text' id="date" ng-model="package.dateB"
                       class="form-control"/>
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Time:</strong>

            <div class='input-group date timepicker' ng-model="package.timeA">
                <input type='text' id="time" ng-model="package.timeB" class="form-control"/>
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Though you already accepted an answer, I'll post it anyways.